# selenium invalid key sequence

Tags: selenium

I'm using the following key sequence,

```
protected void assertFieldValues(String fieldId, String value) {
    focus("id=" + fieldId);
    type("id=" + fieldId, value);
    keyDown("id=" + fieldId, value);
    keyUp("id=" + fieldId, value);
}
```

When I call the method for the first time it works without an issue,

```
public String REQUISITION_TOTAL = "requisitionTotal";

//initially add total
assertFieldValues2(REQUISITION_TOTAL, "1500");
```

When I call it a second time to overwrite the original value,

```
//Overwrite total, but fails. 
assertFieldValues2(REQUISITION_TOTAL, "2500");
```

I get the following error, invalid key sequence. It seems to be failing on keydown, if I remove keydown it fails on keyup.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I need the keyup to run js calculations.

Comment: for which key these values 1500 and 2500 stands?

Comment: My key is requisitionTotal, I'm setting the value 1500 in the field which works perfectly, then I try to overwrite the value with 2500 and it fails.

Comment: What you know about keyup and keydown methods?

Comment: As far as i know these are the keys related to your keyboard..No key of your keyboard has values 1500 or 2500..

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra my issue was related to my use of keyup and keydown. As you indicated, 1500 and 2500 aren't key values but rather field values. I was using the methods incorrectly. If you want to write up a proper answer, I'll mark it off as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which key you want to press down and release up.Say for example if you want to press **"Enter key"** the code will look like this :

```
selenium.keyDown(REQUISITION_TOTAL."\13");
selenium.keyUp(REQUISITION_TOTAL."\13");
```

Where **13 is the key value for Enter Key**.

For mode key codes refer this link [Key Codes and ASCII Values](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html)

Answer (score 0):

Before overwriting the field it's always suggested to clear the previous contents of the field.

```
query = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(fieldId));
query.Clear();
```

i hope this helps...All the best :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however this didn't end up being my solution.